# Do I need to call ThreadLocal.remove in the following case

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-local

Instead of writing the following non-thread safe method.

```
private static final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
public void fun() {
    // Going to call mutable methods in calendar.
}
```

---

I change it to a thread safe version.

```
public void fun() {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Going to call mutable methods in calendar.
}
```

---

Instead of creating a new instance each time even for a same thread, I did the improvement by

```
public void fun() {
    final Calendar calendar = getCalendar();
    // Going to call mutable methods in calendar.
}

/**
 * Returns thread safe calendar.
 * @return thread safe calendar
 */
public Calendar getCalendar() {
    return calendar.get();
}

private static final ThreadLocal <Calendar> calendar = new ThreadLocal <Calendar>() {
    @Override protected Calendar initialValue() {
        return Calendar.getInstance();
     }
 };
```

---

For my 3rd approach, is there any need to call the `ThreadLocal.remove`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your only intent is to make it *threadsafe*, then there is indeed no need to do so. But when the threads are maintained by a threadpool and your intent is more to give each freshly released thread from a threadpool its own initial value, then you should do so.

Answer (score 2):

As @BalusC says, it depends on what you are concerned about.

I have a suspicion that your recycling of `Calendar` objects using a thread local may actually be costing more than you are saving by not calling `Calendar.getInstance()`.  This has the smell of a premature micro-optimization.

Comment: But, Joshua Bloch even suggest using ThreadLocal for SimpleDateFormat example. (I plan to use for Calendar, SimpleDateFormat and NumberFormat) - http://old.nabble.com/Threadlocals-and-memory-leaks-in-J2EE-td13097957.html#a13097957

Comment: But nothing!  Rule #1 of optimization - profile you application first.

Comment: @Yan Cheng `Calendar` should be a quite cheap object to construct.